# Joi validate self-referencing nested schema

Tags: typescript, joi

I am trying to validate a schema that, along other fields, has an array of self-referenced objects like this:

```
export const answer = answerModel.concat(Joi.object().keys({
    childAnswers: Joi.array().items(answer),
    numArray: Joi.array().items(Joi.number()).required()
}))
```

My problem is that I cannot reference answer schema inside answers schema **Joi.array().items(answer)** since I cannot use it before I declare it.

Question is "is there any way to self-reference in this nested format for validation"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Joi.link()`](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/api/?v=17.1.0#linkref) for this purpose:

```
const person = Joi.object({
  firstName: Joi.string().required(),
  lastName: Joi.string().required(),
  friends: Joi.array().items(Joi.link('#person'))
}).id('person');
```

Comment: Amazing guy this David